# Convert array of objects to form data into tabular format

Tags: json, reactjs, lodash

I have following array of objects :

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut",
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

I want following as output :

```
userId | id | title       | completed |
  1    | 1  | delectus aut| false     |
  1    | 2  | quis ut     | false     |
```

I have tried following using *lodash* , but somehow I feel there us better solution than this, considering the number of loops:

```
jsonObject = response; // consider the above mention object here.  
keys = _.keys(json[0]);
```

Here what I found is that `json[0]` will not in all case going to be same, so what is the best way to find the solution for this.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from @Akrion's solution, here is the modified version. 
Little lengthy solution, but this will help you if:

1. You have different keys in your JSON data
2. You have different key sequence in the object
3. Want to set a default value in case data is not available

```js
const json = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "completed": false,
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "quis ut",
    "id": 2,
    "extraProp": "test"
  },
];

const headers = Array.from(new Set(json.reduce((acc, cur) =>
  [...acc, ...Object.keys(cur)], [])));

const data = [headers];
const defaultValue = 'NA';

json.forEach(item => {
  data.push(headers.reduce((acc, header) =>
    acc.push(item.hasOwnProperty(header) ? item[header] : defaultValue) && acc, []));
});
console.log(data);
```

Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zyh1ps

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in a quite simple way with ES6 and no lodash with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let data = [{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut", "completed": false }, { "userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "quis ut", "completed": false } ]

let result = data.reduce((acc,cur) => 
   acc.push(Object.values(cur)) && acc, [Object.keys(data[0])])

console.log(result)
```

It you set as the initial value of the accumulator the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) array then all you need is to push to that accumulator the [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of each iteration in the array. If your header is not always in the first row simply provide it as an array of values etc.

```js
let data = [{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut", "completed": false }, { "userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "quis ut", "completed": false } ]

let hdr = ["userId", "id", "title", "completed"]
let result = data.reduce((acc,cur) => acc.push(Object.values(cur)) && acc, [hdr])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the header of the table :

```
let firstObject = array[0];
let header = Object.keys(firstObject);
```

Now, you have keys in header object.

Use `map` or `forEach` on the array and store that in the variable.

```
let tableValues = table.map((a, i)=>{
    let row = []
    header.forEach((e)=>{row.push(a[e])});
return row;
});
```

Now you have `header` and `tableValues`

`header` is an `array` and `tableValues` is `Array of Array`

Comment: What if some of the data contains extra columns?? array[0] will not going to work in that case

Answer (score 0):

Since you want certain columns in a certain order, you should define an array of keys, and the use `_.map()` and `_.pick()` to get the values in the correct order from the object. Afterwards, concat the array of values to the array of keys:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, map, at, partial, concat, join } = _

const fn = keys => flow(
  pr(map, o => at(o, keys)),
  partial(concat, [keys]),
)

const keys = ['userId', 'id', 'title', 'completed']

const data = [{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut","completed":false},{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut","completed":false}]

const result = fn(keys)(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the terser lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, map, at, concat, join } = _

const fn = keys => flow(
  map(at(keys)),
  concat([keys]),
)

const keys = ['userId', 'id', 'title', 'completed']

const data = [{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut","completed":false},{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut","completed":false}]

const result = fn(keys)(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```